# Gem social_share_buttons don`t work (Rails 5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, haml

I need a social share buttons. I added this gem and I see this buttons on page. But it is not working. It is just reloaded the page.
Code:

View(haml):

```
%td= social_share_button_tag(@photo.name)
```

app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require social-share-button
```

app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss

```
*= require social-share-button
```

Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you don't have any errors anywhere in your JS.

Comment: I think I don`t use any js code in this project because it project so small at this time

Comment: You are using social-share-button JS code, at least.

Comment: Your application is on rails 4 and 5, both?

Comment: My application use Rails 5